# I using rest api to get list of jobs running in nutch (nutch 1.17)

Tags: nutch

I have injected the urls into nutch and crawling using bin/crawl command.
I am using rest api of the nutch i followed this link[enter link description here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NUTCH/Nutch+1.X+RESTAPI#Nutch1.XRESTAPI-Listingalljobs)

I tried listing the jobs in nutch curl -XGET 'http://localhost:8081/job but it is not showing any jobs.may I know the reason.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to launch a crawl via `bin/crawl` and then monitor it over the REST API. Just follow the output of `bin/crawl` to monitor the progress of `bin/crawl`.

Comment: How to create job  that is bin/crawl using rest api i am not able to find any example in docuementation and monitor the jobs using rest api.If possible kindly give me any example.Thanks

Comment: 1. If it's only about monitoring - Hadoop provides a nice monitoring web GUI. But you need to run Nutch is either in pseudo-distributed or fully distributed mode.

2. The webapp component (launched by `bin/nutch webapp`) uses the REST API to launch jobs. However, only the most basic jobs (inject, generate, fetch, parse, updatedb, index) are supported.

Comment: How can I Monitor nutch jobs in hadoop which You mentioned GUI may I know.

Comment: What is best method to monitor nutch jobs and automate nutch jobs.should I go with rest api or commands to run haddop cluster that is emr.

Comment: currently i am using nutch 1.17.can you provide guidance what is way to do production of nutch jobs.

Comment: You should run Nutch from runtime/deploy folder instead of runtime/local. If Hadoop is working fine then you can check job stats at http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8088/cluster. Default port is 8088